# Requirement based on a value from related table, ExpressiveAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressiveannotations

I know I can make some logic based on the columns in the table/model like this:

```
[RequiredIf("ColumnA == 1", ErrorMessage = "Error message")]
```

But is it possible to make a required field if I want to make a check against a column in another table/class. Tables/classes are connected through PK/FK. Something like this:

```
[RequiredIf("DifferentTable.ColumnB == 0"), ErrorMessage = "Error message")]
```

In Views I can access values from different tables using `item.DifferentTable.ColumnB`, is it possible in model and `ExpressiveAnnotations`?

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so, what happened?

Comment: It fails: `[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
`